# Cannot copy $_POST variables into regular variables

Tags: php, variables, post, copy, xampp

I am trying to copy variables from a form into easier-to-write variables like so:

```
$first = $_POST["first"];
$last = $_POST["last"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];
$card = $_POST["card"];
```

I know the $_POST variables have substance because I am able to echo them, see the value I entered from the HTML form, and use the $_POST variables directly in the rest of my code. However, for some reason I keep getting this XAMPP error when I execute the php file:

**Notice: Undefined variable: first in C:\xampp\htdocs\DataFinal.php on line 78**

(I get 1 error for each variable)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the variables exist at that time? That is, where and in which file do you initialize them? Also, are you inside a function on line 78? `$_POST` is a superglobal.

Comment: $_POST variables are 'regular' variables, there is no need to reassign them for fun, and a cost of memory if you do.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you're copying them into variables in some local scope that isn't shared by DataFinal.php's line 78. Otherwise the code you've posted is correct; that is indeed variable assignment. It doesn't get much simpler.

Comment: Awesome, I moved the variables into the function I was calling them from. I was unaware pf PHP's local scopes, I assumed I could declare variables outside functions. Thanks!

Comment: if you use the $_POST array you can, as it's a global, another reason not to reassign

Comment: @KyleY. in case the solution prescribed by meagear worked for you then you can mark it as accepted..for details you may check [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)..